# How do I get the time of day in javascript/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, node.js

I want to get **1 to 24**, 1 being 1am Pacific Time.

How can I get that number in Node.JS?

I want to know what time it is in Pacific time right now.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You should checkout the [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

In particular, you can look at the [getHours()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp) method for the Date object.

getHours() return the time from 0 - 23, so make sure to deal with it accordingly. I think 0-23 is a bit more intuitive since military time runs from 0 - 23, but it's up to you.

With that in mind, the code would be something along the lines of:

```
var date = new Date();
var current_hour = date.getHours();
```

Comment: If you mean rounding with minutes (as in 1:45 -> 2:00), you can use the getMinutes() method for the Date object.

Comment: Link to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. Don't link to that "W3C Schools" fake garbage

Answer (score 150):

This function will return you the date and time in the following format: `YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS`. It also works in Node.js.

```
function getDateTime() {

    var date = new Date();

    var hour = date.getHours();
    hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;

    var min  = date.getMinutes();
    min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

    var sec  = date.getSeconds();
    sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;

    var year = date.getFullYear();

    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;

    var day  = date.getDate();
    day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;

    return year + ":" + month + ":" + day + ":" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;

}
```

Comment: Aww. `(new Date()).toJSON().slice(0, 19).replace(/[-T]/g, ':')`

Comment: @user3125367 Nice one! If flexibility is needed in formatting the date, mine may work better. :-)

Comment: @user3125367 your suggestion while concise is not actually the same.

I just tested it, and getDateTime() returned: `2020:06:10:10:12:35`
whereas, yours returned: `2020:06:10:00:12:35`

It seems it did not consider time zone adjustments.

Answer (score 17):

Check out the [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) library. It works with browsers as well as with Node.JS. Allows you to write

```
moment().hour();
```

or

```
moment().hours();
```

without prior writing of any functions.

Answer (score 13):

Both prior answers are definitely good solutions. If you're amenable to a library, I like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - it does a lot more than just getting/formatting the date.

Answer (score 8):

There's native method to work with date

```
const date = new Date();
let hours = date.getHours();
```

Comment: This seems like a very minor improvement that hinders readability.

Answer (score 7):

If you only want the time string you can use this expression (with a simple RegEx):

```
new Date().toISOString().match(/(\d{2}:){2}\d{2}/)[0]
// "23:00:59"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
var hour = date.getHours();
hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
var day  = date.getDate();
day = (hour > 12 ? "" : "") + day - 1;
day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;
x = ":"
console.log( month + x + day + x + year )
```

It will display the date in the month, day, then the year

Answer (score 0):

For my instance i used it as a global and then called its for a time check of when hours of operation.

Below is from my index.js

```
global.globalDay = new Date().getDay(); 

global.globalHours = new Date().getHours();
```

To call the global's value from another file

```
    /*
     Days of the Week.
     Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wensday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6

     Hours of the Day.
     0 = Midnight, 1 = 1am, 12 = Noon, 18 = 6pm, 23 = 11pm
     */

if (global.globalDay === 6 || global.globalDay === 0) {
     console.log('Its the weekend.');
} else if (global.globalDay > 0 && global.globalDay < 6 && global.globalHours > 8 && global.globalHours < 18) {
     console.log('During Business Hours!');
} else {
     console.log("Outside of Business hours!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To start your node in PST time zone , use following command in ubuntu.

```
TZ=\"/usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT+0\" && export TZ && npm start &
```

Then You can refer [Date Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-management) to get the custom calculation date and time functions in node.

To use it client side refer [this link](https://github.com/digicorp/date-management), download index.js and assertHelper.js and include that in your HTML.

```
<script src="assertHelper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    DateLibrary.getDayOfWeek(new Date("2015-06-15"),{operationType:"Day_of_Week"}); // Output : Monday
}
```

**You can use different functions as given in examples to get custom dates.**

If first day of week is Sunday, what day will be on 15th June 2015.

```
 DateLibrary.getDayOfWeek(new Date("2015-06-15"),
    {operationType:"Day_Number_of_Week",
        startDayOfWeek:"Sunday"}) // Output : 1
```

If first day of week is Tuesday, what week number in year will be
 follow in 15th June 2015 as one of the date.

```
 DateLibrary.getWeekNumber(new Date("2015-06-15"),
    {operationType:"Week_of_Year",
        startDayOfWeek:"Tuesday"}) // Output : 24
```

Refer other functions to fulfill your custom date requirements.