# converting Javascript's Date.now() into timestamp in Stream Analytics

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I tried to collect pressure values by using Node.js in my Raspberry Pi and Azure Stream Analytics in my Azure IoT Hub. I sent the data to IoT Hub as JSON file using this code :

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ 
               deviceId: "myRaspi10",
               pressureVal: value, 
               time:Date.now() 
           });
```

When I checked the console, here's what being sent to the Hub

```
{
    "deviceId":"myRaspi10",
    "pressureVal":39,
    "time":1470642749428
}
```

How to convert the `time` value into timestamp in the Azure Stream Analytics?

Comment: Try sending `new Date()` instead of `Date.now()`. It will produce a string output like "2016-08-08T08:22:34.905Z", which may be Azure Stream Analytics would treat like a date. (Haven't used it though, just an idea).

Comment: @AndrewSklyarevsky will do, currently checking Date section in SO Documentation. Do you have any idea how to simplify the Date() into time only, like "12.34.56.789"?

Comment: See an answer to a different question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16426519/894973

Comment: I've tried various ways, and answer from @AndrewSklyarevsky are the most helpful one. Mind if you create an answer for that? So I can vote it

Comment: Oh, cool, I don't actually use Azure Stream Analytics but I am glad that that idea helped you.

Comment: @AndrewSklyarevsky the problem is actually at the JavaScript. Once I used your solution, the Stream Analytics can interpreted it as datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending `new Date()` instead of `Date.now()`. It will produce a string output like `"2016-08-08T08:22:34‌​.905Z"` which may be Azure Stream Analytics would treat like a date. (Haven't used it though, just an idea).

Answer (score 1):

@nobodykid, you can use [Stream Analyics Query Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn834998.aspx) to convert `time` from `bigint` to `datetime` as below.

```
CAST(time AS datetime)
```

Please refer to the buildin [`CAST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn834995.aspx) function and the [supported data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn835065.aspx#Anchor_0) for conversions.

Answer (score 0):

According to Azure stream Analytics date type references https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835065.aspx datetime is represented as string converted to datetime following ISO 8601 standard.

Use javascript Date  object and call toISOString()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString